# Locking multiple functions executed by different threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have two functions, `Funct1` and `Funct2`. They both are internally calling `Funct3`. `Funct`1 and `Funct2` are called by 2 different threads.

What I want is, when `Funct1` is in progress by `Thread1`, then `Func2` should not be called by `Thread2`, or basically `Funct3` should not be called by both threads at the same time.

If I use mutex in both `Funct1` and `Funct2`, and execution of `Funct1` starts, then will this mutex prohibit `Funct2` to start?

What should be done in such situation? Here is the sample code:

```
class A
 {
 boost::mutex mtx;
 public:
       void Func1()
       {
          boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(this->mtx);
          /* -------- */
          Func3();
       }
       void Func2()
       {
          boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(this->mtx);
          /* --------- */
          Func3();
       }
       void Func3()
       {
          //do something
       }
  };
```

Comment: Mutexes are only meaningful if the code block accessed (executed) by more than one thread. In your case, it seems Func3 is the only place that is executed by the both threads. Why don't you insert `lock` in the Func3?

Comment: No, Func1 is also executed by 10 threads, and Func2 is running in a different thread.

Answer (score 0):

If Func1() can be called from multiple threads and run free in parallel as long Func2 is not running and Func2() can only run if no Func1() is not running then you probably need a shared lock. 
Func1 should obtain shared locks before running and Func2 should get an exclusive lock before running. It is the classic many readers, one writer problem.